# codeigniter: closure table - add descendant

Tags: php, codeigniter, hierarchical-data, transitive-closure-table

I'm trying to add a new descendant, but having difficulties achieving it, it displays some error, Would be grateful if you could take time to review what I've done thus far.

Here's

Controller

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->view('closure_view');
    }
    public function add() {

        $add_new = array(
            'ancestor'      => $this->input->post('ancestor'),
            'descendant'        => $this->input->post('descendant'),
            'lvl'   => $this->input->post('lvl'),
            'id'    => $this->input->post('id')
        );

        $cust_id = $this->closure->add($add_new);
        redirect('http://localhost/kgmerchant/index.php/welcome');
    }
```

Model

```
public $table;
    public $closure_table = 'closures';
    public function __construct($table_name = NULL, $closure_table = NULL){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = $table_name;
        if ($closure_table !== NULL) {
            $this->closure_table = $closure_table;
        }
    }
public function add($node_id, $target_id = 0) {
        $sql = 'SELECT ancestor, '.$node_id.', lvl+1
                FROM '.$this->closure_table.'
                WHERE descendant = '.$target_id.'
                UNION
                SELECT '.$node_id.','.$node_id.',0';
        $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->closure_table.' (ancestor, descendant, lvl) ('.$sql.')';
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        return $result;
    }
```

View

```
<form name="home" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/home/add' ?>" >    
            <input placeholder="ancestor" type="text" name="ancestor"  required/>    
            <input placeholder="descendant" type="text" name="descendant"  required/>
            <input placeholder="lvl" type="text" name="lvl" required />
            <input placeholder="id" type="hidden" name="id" value="" />    
            <input type="submit" value="Okay" />   

        </form>
```

Thanks.

Error

> Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: Just a tip you don't need to have redirect like         `redirect('http://localhost/kgmerchant/index.php/welcome');` if you set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/kgmerchant/';` then autoload url helper you can then use redirect like `redirect(base_url('welcome'))`

Comment: can you show the errors?

Comment: @prakashtank, I've update with the error

Comment: @wolfgang1983, Thanks

Comment: The error message is clear: you can't to declare a new class with a name already used in your application.

Comment: I've updated the error message

Comment: Please make sure you create a [mcve] and post the full error message you receive, including details which you don't understand. Since you've now posted two different errors here, it looks like you're still in the middle of debugging this, and can probably narrow down the problem further before asking for help.

Comment: @IMSoP, Thanks, the first error was from session, which I've fixed.

Comment: @prakashtank, Please can you help with a solution?

Comment: @N.francis : I hope you got the solution if not then please echo your query and check the output by executing `echo $this->db->last_query();` function. the error you are showing here is that you are getting array and you are passing it into the query.

Comment: Hi @prakashtank, I haven't found a solution yet, I'm using [https://gist.github.com/dazld/2174233](https://gist.github.com/dazld/2174233) as a guideline to implement a controller, but finding it challenging to implement. please could you use a bit of your time to review it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your model can't be called "Closure" because that's a reserved name in PHP. Change the name to something else and it should work.

Comment: Hi, I just did that, but have an error, I've updated the error message

Comment: You're calling `$this->closure->add($add_new);` where $add_new is an array, but then in the `add` method you're expecting 2 parameters and using them separately. Either pass the parameters separately to `add()` or change the method so that it uses the array items.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to achieve a closure table, Do you have a better way I could modify the model, I guess that's where bulk of the bug is. Thanks