# Codeigniter: Controller issues with Closure table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transitive-closure-table

I'm having issues implementing a controller for a closure table, I'm trying to INSERT a descendant.

Here's what I've done

Controller

```
public function add() {    
    $this->load->model('home_model', 'closures');

    $node_id = $this->input->post('ancestor');
    $target = array(
        'descendant' => $this->input->post('descendant'),
        'lvl' => $this->input->post('lvl'),
        'id' => $this->input->post('id')
    );  

    $cust_id = $this->closures->add($node_id, $target);
    $this->index();    
    redirect(site_url());
}
```

Model

```
 public function add($node_id, $target_id = 0) {
    $sql = 'SELECT ancestor, '.$node_id.', lvl+1
            FROM '.$this->closure_table.'
            WHERE descendant = '.$target_id.'
            UNION ALL SELECT '.$node_id.','.$node_id.',0';
    $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->closure_table.'(ancestor, descendant, lvl) ('.$sql.')';
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

View

```
<form name="closures" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/home/add' ?>" >
    <input placeholder="ancestor" type="text" name="ancestor"  required/>

    <input placeholder="descendant" type="text" name="descendant"  required/>
    <input placeholder="lvl" type="text" name="lvl" />
    <input placeholder="id" type="hidden" name="id" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Okay" />
</form>
```

Error messages
1. Array to string conversion
2. Syntax error on the model after UNION.

I'm having some challenges resolving the error messages

Comment: Thanks for including the code, but what is the issue are you getting an error/ how do you know it's failing

Comment: Hi @TMin here are the errors ** Array to string conversion**

Comment: Is there a way i could resolve this?

Comment: Havent you already asked similar questions twice today on this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075708/codeigniter-inserting-into-closure-table - and - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073695/codeigniter-closure-table-add-descendant

Comment: Hi, yes I did, I felt I didn't ask properly

Comment: So delete your other questions, or better yet, edit them to reflect your question more clearly and then wait for responses / potential answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will do that

Comment: You are unclear what the actual problem is. Provide the full error message and include it in the question.

Comment: @RidIculous I've updated with the error messages

Comment: Without line numbers and context they are meaningless. And few people will attend to syntax errors here. If you can't work these out you're probably not the right person for the job.

Comment: Thanks, I used another method to solve it